# How can i animate the spin property for curves (extruding while rotating)

Tags: animation

I'm trying to make a video explaining "Solids of revolutions" in calculus; i need to animate the "spin" tool, i have looked it up, and all what i found talks about rotations, which is not what i'm looking for, by spinning i mean using this command line

```
bpy.ops.mesh.spin(steps = 90,angle = 2 *math.pi, center=(0, 0, 0), axis = (1, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use the screw modifier and animate the angle property.

Here is my mesh that is curved and only an edge. I apply the Screw modifier and set Angle to 0. Then I hover over the Angle box and hit **i**. This adds a key frame to that property. Go to the frame where you want it to be fully spun and set degrees to 360 and hit **i** again over the green box. It should turn yellow.
[image]

[image]

Now, it should be animated! Here is a still mid animation.
[image]

Comment: you're awesome, it worked, but i have another question if you may, can I somehow animate each segment in the curve separately without separating the curve into 9000 layers? (the curve is just (cos(x)) )

Comment: @BoudMath Hm. Could you give me a picture of what you want to do exactly? Maybe I can create something for you to play around with.